# Join lines which start with spaces to previous line

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that has some data of the following format that I want to extract and append.  I'm new to Python and would like some advice on the approach.

Data Format is as follows:

Position 1 is a number followed by 5 white spaces followed by non-white space of variable length then no more data.  However the next line has non white space starting in position 6 and the remainder of the data that I need from that line.  I want to take the second line and append it to the first line and then print it.

Example

```
1     Some variable data           
<6 Spaces>      More Data that I want above          ea     5       ...
2     another line of data
```

I want it to look like:

```
1     Some variable data More Data that I want above       ea     5   ...
2     another line of data
```

This is what I started with but then realized not every line has a unit of issue = ea.  Some lines wrap.  I need to account for that.

```
import re
# Open fie for reading
fileObject = open("AFilenameHere.txt", "r")
fn=fileObject.name

#Read a file line by line and print in terminal
for line in fileObject:
 if ' EA ' in line:

# break up string
  part1=line.split()
  EAISAT=part1.index('EA')
  DESC=' '.join(part1[1:EAISAT])
  # If there's a comma in the descr take it out cause I wanna eventually create a csv
  transformed_desc = re.sub(",","", DESC)
  num_of_elements = len(part1)

  # If there's nothing in the description then don't print those lines
  if DESC:

    print (fn, part1[0], transformed_desc, part1[EAISAT:num_of_elements])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just collect lines until you get one which doesn't have the six spaces, and *then* print what you have accrued so far before starting over.  Don't forget to handle the last one when you fall off the end of the loop.

```
fn = "AFilenameHere.txt"
lines = []
with open(fn, "r") as fileObject:
    for line in fileObject:
        if line.startswith('      '):
            lines.append(line[5:])
        else:
            if lines:
                print("".join(lines))
            lines = [line]
if lines:
    print("".join(lines))
```

The `if lines:` condition checks if there are items in `lines` from the *previous* iterations of the `for` loop, and if so, prints those.

It's not clear why your attempt looks for the "EA" token; by your description, this simply joins lines which have multiple spaces back with the previous line.

Comment: The files are large text files with just a small subsection of data that I need to tease out.  I initially thought every line I cared about had a unit of issue of EA so I'd just grab all of those...  Didn't work out as there are numerous wraps.  Let me try what you've suggested and see what I can do with it and thank you so much.  I've just learned there are line.startswith which is pretty cool.

Comment: I think it comes down to 2 regular expressions such that I need to find a line that matches
'line begins with 1 space followed by non-white space of up to 2 characters followed by 5 spaces and then non-white space for the first line.'

The second line that would be appended to the first line starts with
6 spaces followed by the rest of the line.  

Reading through the regex docs now.  Seeing lot's of good individual examples.